# Loading a string file as a json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Am trying a load a string file into a json format.

```
data = '{"name":"xxx", "truncated":false, "text":"hi this is going weird"}'
       '{"name":"yyy", "truncated":false, "text":"I am not able to identify this"}'
```

The above data is being loaded from different directories and hence looks like this.

```
print(type(data))
out : <class 'str'>
      <class 'str'>
```

I want to convert this into a json dictionary using the below command and it throws me error:

```
data = json.loads((data))
```

Error:  `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)`

Comment: That's not valid JSON or Python.

Comment: Please post a proper MCVE - your current code snippet is invalid so no one can help you.

Comment: I have a '\n' after every end of statement which caused this issue. I have solved this.

Answer (score 0):

You should pack your data this way:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "name": "xxx",
        "truncated": false,
        "text": "hi this is going weird"
    }, {
        "name": "yyy",
        "truncated": false,
        "text": "I am not able to identify this"
    }]
}
```

Comment: can you please check now

Comment: the data is not packed as each string is taken from different directories